# Page break between multiple instances of a group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to be able to have a page break after a group has repeated three times on a page, my resulting report is a tablix of customers and details that repeat for each differnt cutomerID but I want to limit the repeating tablix to three instances per page when outputing to a pdf file. Any ideas? Tried all other avenues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the tablix inside another tablix, on the details, under Row Groups, group properties, Group on.

Add this expression to give three rows per page:

```
=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)
```